# Recommended approach to load proprietary binary image file into NSImage?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a bunch of image files in a proprietary binary format that I want to load into NSImages. The format is not a simple bitmap, but rather a kind of an RLE representation mixed with transparency and miscellaneous additional information.

In order to display one of these images in a Cocoa app, I need a way to parse the image file byte by byte and "calculate" a bitmap from it which I will then put into an NSImage.

What is a good approach for doing this in Objective-C/Cocoa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tasks of interpreting image data are handled by the image's representation object(s). To use a proprietary format, you have a few options: (a) create a custom representation class, (b) use `NSCustomImageRep` with a custom delegate, or (c) use a custom object to translate your image to a supported format, such as a raw bitmap.

If you choose to create a custom representation class, you will create a subclass of `NSImageRep` as described in [Creating New Image Representation Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Images/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH208-BCIFJBGC). This basically requires that your class register itself and be able to draw the image data. In addition to this, you can override methods to return information about the image, and you will be able to instantiate your images using the normal `NSImage` methods. This method requires the most work.

Using [`NSCustomImageRep`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCustomImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSCustomImageRep) requires less work than creating a custom implementation. Your delegate object only needs to be able to draw the image at a fixed location. However, you cannot return other information about the image, and you will need to create the `NSCustomImageRep` object manually before creating the `NSImage`.

Translating the image into a different format is also simpler than creating a custom representation. It could be as simple as creating a blank `NSImage` of the proper size and drawing into it. Creating the image is still more complicated since you need to call your translation method, and this will affect efficiency (both future drawing time and memory usage) since you are changing formats, which could be good or bad. You will also lose any association between the image object and its source.

Comment: Nice summary of the options available, thanks! As for the third option: I would only have to do the conversion once, when creating the `NSImage`, right? How would this affect future drawing time? Also, what is the most efficient way for drawing into an `NSImage`? I read somewhere about a solution that involved creating an `NSColor` object each time a pixel was written. That does not seem too efficient as I need to process several hundred megabytes of image data.

Comment: @tajmahal Yes, you would only do the drawing once. In the future, drawing would be done using whatever format you converted to, which would probably be as fast as possible if you just draw into the image. If your format is a bitmap format, you could "draw" it by changing it into a bitmap format `NSImage` supports instead of creating color objects and drawing single pixels. If your format is a vector format, you would want to use Cocoa drawing methods or Core Graphics functions to draw it. CG also has shading objects which let you provide the color at each pixel through a function.